# Decorating a Java library object with Scala

Tags: java, scala

I'm relying on an old Java API that kinda sucks and loves to throw null pointer exceptions when data is missing. I want to create a subclass that has option type accessors but preserves the old accessors until I decide I need to create safe accessors for them. Is there a good way to create a subclass from a copy of the original object? I'd like to achieve something like the following:

```
SafeIssue extends Issue {
  def safeMethod: Option[Value] = { //... }
}


val issue = oldapi.getIssue()
val safeIssue = SafeIssue(issue)

//Preserves issue's methods and data if I need them
val unsafeVal = safeIssue.unsafeMethod
val maybeVal  = safeIssue.safeMethod
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not try an implicit conversion instead?  This works better with Java APIs that like to create their own objects.  So you would

```
class SafeIssue(issue: Issue) {
  def original = issue
  def safeFoo = Option(issue.foo)
  // ...  You must write any of these you need
}
implicit def make_issues_safe(issue: Issue) = new SafeIssue(issue)
```

Then you can--as long as you've supplied the method--write things like

```
val yay = Issue.myStaticFactoryMethodThing.safeFoo.map(x => pleaseNoNull(x))
```

(You can then decide whether you want to carry `SafeIssue` or `Issue` around in your code, and you can always get back the `Issue` from `SafeIssue` with the exposed `original` method (or you could make the `issue` parameter a `val`.)

Comment: Great, that works just as expected. This is a little pedantic, but I wasn't sure where to put the implicit conversion according to your answer. Looked it up and in my case it belonged in a companion object, but it could sit elsewhere depending on the situation. 

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @sbilstein This pattern is called "pimp my library".

Comment: @T.Grottker - Also "enrich my library" for those who insist on etymology with entirely noncontroversial roots.